# How can I make log4perl create log directory if it doesn't exist?

Tags: perl, log4perl

If my logging directory (`/home/hss/Data/log/DataImport.log`) does not exist when log4perl is initializing, then I get this error:

```
Cannot write to '/home/hss/Data/log/DataImport.log': No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to make it create the directory by itself without me having to specify the directory anywhere except in my log.conf file?

Answer (score 1):

I am quite sure that `Log::Log4perl::Appender::File` do not create any directories. Probably easiest method would be to subclass it and override `file_open` method with directory detection/creation code, followed by call original method.

Comment: ah.. I guess I'll have to just try to ensure that the directory exists

Answer (score 1):

From version 1.43 on there is a new parameter called mkpath in Log::Log4perl::Appender::File which creates the directory if it is set to true in the config.

Docu 1.43: http://search.cpan.org/dist/Log-Log4perl-1.43/lib/Log/Log4perl/Appender/File.pm